# How to save a nltk FreqDist plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, nltk

I've tried different methods to save my plot but every thing I've tried has turned up with a blank image and I'm not currently out of ideas. Any help with other suggestions that could fix this? The code sample is below.

```
word_frequency = nltk.FreqDist(merged_lemmatizedTokens) #obtains frequency distribution for each token
print("\nMost frequent top-10 words: ", word_frequency.most_common(10))
word_frequency.plot(10, title='Top 10 Most Common Words in Corpus')
plt.savefig('img_top10_common.png')
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to save the NLTK FreqDist plot, when I first initialized a figure object, then called the plot function and finally saved the figure object.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,4))
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15) # to avoid x-ticks cut-off
fdist = FreqDist(merged_lemmatizedTokens)
fdist.plot(10, cumulative=False)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('freqDist.png', bbox_inches = "tight")
```

Comment: Don't forget the "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" statement otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Good point, I added it to my solution. I assumed, it is already included.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the following:

```
plt.ion()
word_frequency.plot(10, title='Top 10 Most Common Words in Corpus')
plt.savefig('img_top10_common.png')
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

This is because inside nltk's `plot` function, `plt.show()` is called and once the figure is closed, `plt.savefig()` has no active figure to save anymore.

The workaround is to turn interactive mode on, such that the `plt.show()` from inside the nltk function does not block. Then savefig is called with a current figure available and saves the correct plot. To then show the figure, interactive mode needs to be turned off again and `plt.show()` be called externally - this time in a blocking mode.

Ideally, `nltk` would rewrite their plotting function to either allow to set the blocking status, or to not `show` the plot and return the created figure, or to take a `Axes` as input to which to plot. Feel free to reach out to them with this request.

Comment: I just tested this out and unfortunately this also failed to work, what you have said does make complete sense to me though

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, the way I solved it was to use the parameter `show=False` in the `plot()` function, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/2786)  by a member of the NLTK library.
Your code would remain as follows:

```
word_frequency = nltk.FreqDist(merged_lemmatizedTokens)
print("\nMost frequent top-10 words: ", word_frequency.most_common(10))
word_frequency.plot(10, show=False, title='Top 10 Most Common Words in Corpus')
plt.savefig('img_top10_common.png')
```

It is important not to include `plt.show()` before `plt.savefig()`, as this will save a blank figure.

Comment: This is actually the method that worked for me.