# Plotting two nltk freqdists

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

I have been following the stylometry tutorial that can be found here([programminghistorian.com](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/introduction-to-stylometry-with-python#calculating-z-scores)). This uses matplotlib to plot the frequency distribution of some text. The relevant code is below:

```
for author in authors:
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(federalist_by_author[author])

# Filter out punctuation
federalist_by_author_tokens[author] = ([token for token in tokens
                                        if any(c.isalpha() for c in token)])

# Get a distribution of token lengths
token_lengths = [len(token) for token in federalist_by_author_tokens[author]]
federalist_by_author_length_distributions[author] = nltk.FreqDist(token_lengths)
federalist_by_author_length_distributions[author].plot(15, title=author)
```

Unfortunately, try as I might, I don't seem to be able to overlay these distributions onto the same pyplot - using this code just opens up a new plot for each author one at a time rather than the usual matplotlib 'plt.plot()' behaviour of adding them to the same pyplot which is what I would like.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908305/how-to-save-a-nltk-freqdist-plot/52908701#52908701) which has been asked a few hours earlier, you will need to trick the nltk function's `show()` not to take effect by plotting in interactive mode:

```
# turn interactive on
plt.ion()
# your code :
for foo in bars:
    frqdst = nltk.FreqDist(...)
    frqdst.plot(...)
# turn interactive off
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything [in the source of `FreqDist`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/probability.html#FreqDist.plot) that would force opening a new window. (Let's ignore for now that the source uses `pylab` instead of `pyplot` for no good reason; this is a very bad practice).

I suspect what's going on is that the final `pylab.show()` call pops up the figure window with the first plot, and blocks until this first figure is closed. If this is the case, calling `plt.ion()` at the start in order to enable interactive mode might make the call to `show()` non-blocking, and you'll get your plots in the same single figure as expected.